# Remove characters after string?

Tags: php, string, replace

I have strings that looks like this:

```
John Miller-Doe - Name: jdoe
Jane Smith - Name: jsmith
Peter Piper - Name: ppiper
Bob Mackey-O'Donnell - Name: bmackeyodonnell
```

I'm trying to remove everything after the second hyphen, so that I'm left with:

```
John Miller-Doe
Jane Smith
Peter Piper
Bob Mackey-O'Donnell
```

So, basically, I'm trying to find a way to chop it off right before "- Name:".  I've been playing around with substr and preg_replace, but I can't seem to get the results I'm hoping for... Can someone help?

Comment: Can there be a `John Miller - Doe - Name:`? Will there always be `Name: ` at the end?

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->beforeLast('-')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L399) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming that the strings will always have this format, one possibility is:

```
$short = substr($str, 0, strpos( $str, ' - Name:'));
```

Reference: [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 7):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) with the pattern `/ - Name:.*/`:

```
<?php
$text = "John Miller-Doe - Name: jdoe
Jane Smith - Name: jsmith
Peter Piper - Name: ppiper
Bob Mackey-O'Donnell - Name: bmackeyodonnell";

$result = preg_replace("/ - Name:.*/", "", $text);
echo "result: {$result}\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
result: John Miller-Doe 
Jane Smith 
Peter Piper 
Bob Mackey-O'Donnell
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer could be use for any string.

Answer (score 2):

Everything after right before the second hyphen then, correct? One method would be

```
$string="Bob Mackey-O'Donnell - Name: bmackeyodonnel";
$remove=strrchr($string,'-');
//remove is now "- Name: bmackeyodonnell"
$string=str_replace(" $remove","",$string);
//note $remove is in quotes with a space before it, to get the space, too
//$string is now "Bob Mackey-O'Donnell"
```

Just thought I'd throw that out there as a bizarre alternative.

Comment: Thanks for sharing mate. i love this way and it works for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
$string="Bob Mackey-O'Donnell - Name: bmackeyodonnell";
$parts=explode("- Name:",$string);   
$name=$parts[0];
```

Though the solution after mine is much nicer...

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way:

```
$find = 'Name';
$fullString = 'aoisdjaoisjdoisjdNameoiasjdoijdsf';
$output = strstr($fullString, $find, true) . $find ?: $fullString;
```